# Chef recipe to delete environment variables

Tags: chef-infra

How I write a chef recipe to delete a environment variables

I have used unset command but is not working

Answer (score 0):

In what context? If you mean from the Chef memory space, you do that with the normal `ENV.delete` API from Ruby (not Chef specific).

What you probably mean is some kind of "global environment variable" which is not a thing in Unix. You'll probably have to find which shell initialization file is setting it, and then remove that file (or edit it, if you really have to).

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Comment: But I have check one resource env for that but that is also not working. Yes I want to delete global environment variables